# Combobox values do not update dynamically

Tags: vb.net, binding, combobox, refresh

I am using the following code to write a 'Tarrif' value to my database.

```
'import name into Tarrif table
Using cmdb = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Tarrifs (Tarrif) VALUES (@tarrif2)", con)
con.Open()
cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarrif2", TextBox1.Text)
cmdb.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
End Using
End Using
```

I then on the same form want to select the newly crated value from a combobox that links to this data source.

However the combobox values do not update dynamically.

At the moment I have to close and re-open the application. How can I force a refresh of the data/list in Combobox1, so that it is immediate available for selection?

Update: the Combobox is bound to an object called 'TarrifsBindingSource'

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
Form1_Load(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Which seems to have done the trick

Comment: Forcing the form to reload by calling an event handler is not a great idea.  Are you using winforms?  You probably want to simply force a rebinding of `TarrifsBindingSource` or hook into the combobox's OnChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you were to set the ComboBox's `.ItemSource` property by saying

`Combobox1.ItemsSource = TarrifsBindingSource`

and then whenever you need the values to update, you can say

`Combobox1.Items.Refresh()`.

ComboBoxes seem to be really frustrating in VB.Net to use for your purpose. I'm currently working on something similar, but it's constantly bringing up trouble.